# Installing cumulative updates on SP2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, error, cumulative-update

I have a single server farm, a SP Server 2010 migrated to SP server 2013. The current version is `15.0.4571.1502`. I wanted to install the last CU but i get the error that an error occurred.

[image]

I found posts of people with the same problem, tried to solve mine as they did, but without success. I also tried to take the next CU after my version (`April 2014 15.0.4605.1004`), gives the same error. Tried to check the msi temp file in order to find something that would help me to figure out the problem, but nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: Should you check the event viewer , you might get some details about the issue , and please put it here if you find any thing useful

Comment: I did it, but it's not easy to look for something you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

there are different reason for this error but you can try runt he CU via command line with bypassdetection of version number.

1. Open the command prompt and browse to the folder where CU is save.
2. Now Run the command like this `sts2013-kb3114733-fullfile-x64-glb.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1`
3. once it installed then run the config wizard.

Comment: Bypass the detection....is it safe? What problems may I encounter?

Comment: i did in my production farm, it is safe rather it fix the problem for future. I would go with latest CU instead security fix. Reason,in our case was MSI file got deleted from the system folders

Comment: I don't think to skip the version detection is the right way. If the system tells that something is not ok there must be a way to figure out what and why.

Comment: Issue is there are some MSI and MSP files missing from Windows Installer folder which is causing the issue. why, i am not sure, may be somebody delete it? Now to fix, you can run the bypass thing which Hopefully install the missing MSPs and fix it for future. Or you can compare the installer folders with working server and install the missing one or you can rebuild the server. choices are yours.